# ASUS PCE-AX58BT not recognised on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, asus, pcie

New to Linux and trying to get wifi set up.

Have installed the PCIe card as per instructions.

Correct firmware in appropriate lib/firmware location.

CONFIG_FW_LOADER enabled.

However, the system is not detecting the card (lspci and lshw -c network).

I have trawled various forums and tried a variety of things but to no avail. Does anyone have any suggestions or is it a case of trying a different card?

Many thanks.

Comment: If the device is not shown in `lspci` output then it is not installed properly, or is broken, or incompatible with the motherboard. It is not a matter of drivers or firmware. Even a completely unsupported by Ubuntu device should be shown. You didn't provide any hardware information, or the `lspci` output.

Comment: Hey thanks, that's super helpful. Apologies for the lack of information/output.